# Google Form Drop Down and Sections with Loop

Tags: javascript, forms, loops, google-sheets, addition

So I have this project I am working on where I need to create a Google Form based on names in a Google Sheet. The way it basically needs to flow is for every name in the sheet should be an option as a drop down in section one and then have a section created for each name. When the person selects their name in the first section they should then be sent to the section titled their name. For example, Name 1 should go to the section titled Name 1, Name 2 to Name 2, etc. The code below will create a Google Form and create sections with the names. The issue that arouses is it will not add the names to a drop down list (it will create a drop down list with no options) and will also not set a destination based on the answers. Any thoughts?

```js
function RecommendationForm(){
  var form = FormApp.create('FANS Recommendation Form');
  form.setTitle('FANS Recommendation Form')
     .setConfirmationMessage('Thanks for responding!')//SET CONFIRMATION MESSAGE LATER
     .setAllowResponseEdits(false)
     .setAcceptingResponses(true);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Teacher and Email List');
  var startRow = 2;
  var numRows = 200;
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 4)
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var whoAreYou = form.addListItem();
  whoAreYou.setTitle('Who are you?')
  var nameBreak = []
  var nameChoice = []
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var name = row[0];
    var recNumber = row[2]
    if (name != ""){
    if (recNumber != 0){
    nameBreak[i] = form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle(name);
    nameChoice[i] = name
    }}};
  whoAreYou.setChoices([
    whoAreYou.createChoice(nameChoice,nameBreak) 
  ])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You got the syntax of the setChoices function wrong. You need to create an array of choices like so:

```
var choices = []
choices[i] = whoAreYou.createChoice(name,form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle(name))
```

Then you can use this array in setChoices method to set all your choices.

```
 whoAreYou.setChoices(choices)
```

for more details have a look [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/list-item#setChoices(Choice))

Below is the modified code that incorporates these changes,

```
function RecommendationForm(){
  var form = FormApp.create('FANS Recommendation Form');
  //var form = FormApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/forms/d/11oaebH_BeFLAkpGjqs5EykqtNxXXaabuVCTk3uuc12s/edit")
  form.setTitle('FANS Recommendation Form')
     .setConfirmationMessage('Thanks for responding!')//SET CONFIRMATION MESSAGE LATER
     .setAllowResponseEdits(false)
     .setAcceptingResponses(true);
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet9');
  var startRow = 2;
  var numRows = 10;
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 4)
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var whoAreYou = form.addListItem();
  whoAreYou.setTitle('Who are you?')
  var nameBreak
  var nameChoice
  var choices = []
  var choiceCounter = 0
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var name = row[0];
    var recNumber = row[2]
    if (name != ""){
    if (recNumber != 0){
    nameBreak = form.addPageBreakItem().setTitle(name);
    nameChoice = name
    choices[choiceCounter] = whoAreYou.createChoice(nameChoice,nameBreak)  // Create a array of choices with the navigation item 
    choiceCounter++;                                        // This counter will be independent of i counter and will be have no breaks. 
    }}

  };
  whoAreYou.setChoices(choices)  //Set Choices with the choice array. 
  Logger.log(form.getEditUrl())
  Logger.log(form.getPublishedUrl())
}
```

Hope this helps!